# Why is the header not centered with body margin?

Tags: html, css, viewport

Below, I fixed a header to the top, set `width: 100%` and applied a margin to the `body` element of `margin: 10%`. I expected the header to remain at 100% width of the viewport, but instead it now has a left margin but reaches to the end of the viewport on the right side.

```css
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            
            
        
            header {
                position: fixed;
                background-color: #59b1ff;
                top: 0;
                height: 20px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            body {
                margin: 20%;
            }
            
            div {
                border: 1px solid grey;
            }
```

```html
<header>Header</header>

<main>
<div>Div</div>
</main>
```

Why is the header not attached to the left viewport edge?

Comment: _“but reaches to the end of the viewport on the right side”_ - no, it actually goes beyond that, it doesn’t “stop” at the right viewport edge. (Easy to see if you f.e. hover over the element in dev tools.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the header not attached to the left viewport edge?

Because you did not *specify* where you want its left edge to be.

You basically left `left` at the default `auto`, so it takes the natural position this element *would* have in the flow if it wasn’t positioned, into account.

Add `left: 0`, and it will behave like you want it to.

Comment: when we set width: 100% is it the 100% of its parent or view-port?

Comment: So a fixed element uses the viewport to calculate the percentages, but it still respects the margins of the parent container?

Comment: @MahdyAslamy it's 100% and it's overflowing like you can see.

Comment: @TMOTTM size is something and position is something else. If you don't specify the position then the browser will decide and why should it be the left by default? why not the center, the right, etc ... so by default it will be the initial position

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's the question, how does `fixed` affect the default references.

Comment: @TMOTTM fixed has nothing to do here, you will have the same using absolute, relative, sticky, etc ... the default is the same for all the position and it's [like described in the answer] the position of the element before the use of position

Answer (score 0):

Just add `left: 0`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #59b1ff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 20%;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>

<main>
<div>Div</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with your header element. Whenever you use fixed or absolute positioning, you also have to specify the left, right or top (according to your needs) in your fixed element.

```css
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            
            
        
            header {
                position: fixed;
                background-color: #59b1ff;
                top: 0;
                height: 20px;
                width: 100%;
                left:0;  /*Added this*/
                right:0; /*Added this*/
            }
            
            body {
                margin: 20%;
            }
            
            div {
                border: 1px solid grey;
            }
```

```html
<header>Header</header>

<main>
<div>Div</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Yes, and if `left` is not specified, the default is to reference the body margins.

Comment: Yes , fixed and absolute element are on auto float :D unless you specify their left right top bottom properties

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #59b1ff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; /* stick the header to the viewport's left */
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative; /* allows the header to be positioned relative to the body */
  margin: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set left property zero.you set it default, it will takes the natural position this element would have in the flow.